# How to evaluating inconsistency and heterogeneity in a frequentist Network meta-analysis based exclusively on multi-armed studies?

Tags: stata, frequentist, network-meta-analysis

I have been trying to perform a network meta-analysis on a set of 5 multi-armed trials, each having 3 arms (placebo, treatment 1, and treatment 2). I am using the network and network graphs packages on STATA for this and my effect measure is lnOR.

I am relatively new to NMA, and am completely lost on how to calculate inconsistency and heterogeneity in this instance. Using the inconsistency option in network meta is out of the question since $df=0$ for consistency. The node-splitting model isn't working either.

Do I even need to perform a network meta here or can I get away with multiple traditional pairwise comparisons as I only have multi-armed trials with direct comparisons?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.